# Amazon AWS listObjects call error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to call a method `listObjects` on my Amazon S3 Bucket using the Node.js SDK. However I am getting an error on the keyword `require`. The API I am using is [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) and [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3_20060301.html#listObjects-property). I also have installed AWS-SDK via NPM. The version of node I have is v0.10.18.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('credentials.json');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});
listObjects(params = {Bucket:'wepicit.s3.amazonaws.com'}, function(data,err){
  console.log(data);
  console.log('Error'+err);
});
```

Assistance is appreciated.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: It throws an error on the require keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to install the aws sdk by calling "npm install aws-sdk" in a command-line, from your script directory.